# How to merge row with same year different months to get total quantity?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way I can combine all dates within a column that are within the same year into one row, so that I may know the total quantity of a product in a different column for that year?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Group_Concat` or `Group by`

```
Select Group_Concat(col_name) From table Group by Year(date)
```

or

```
Select Group_Concat(col_name) From table 
where Year(date)='2015' Group by Year(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `YEAR()` function:

```
SELECT YEAR(someDate) AS year, SUM(qty) AS `total quantity`
FROM someTable
WHERE product='some product'
GROUP BY YEAR(someDate)
```